# Can a .NET Core 3.1 C++/CLI assembly use types like System.Windows.Rect?

Tags: .net-core, c++-cli

Is there anything I can do to make a .NET-Core 3.1 based C++/CLI assembly use types like System::Windows::Rect?  Is there any NuGet, "compatibility" package I can add that will make it work?

As a test, I created a simple .NET Core 3.1 C++/CLI class Library project from the template Microsoft Provided using the instructions here:

```
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/an-update-on-cpp-cli-and-dotnet-core/
```

I verified that I have installed all the stuff they say you need to have installed (cross-platform and desktop development).  Then I tried exposing a property of type System::Windows::Rect from the boilerplate class they generated

```
public ref class Class1
{
public:

    property System::Windows::Rect MyRect { System::Windows::Rect get(); }
};
```

Unfortunately the compiler has no idea what System::Windows::Rect is.  I tried adding the NuGet `Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility` package but that had no effect.

Is this possible?

Edit:  I should say that I've looked in the list of references and I do see WindowsBase.dll in there.  And the project settings look right:

[image]

Comment: It compiles with #using "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\3.1.0\ref\netcoreapp3.1\WindowsBase.dll"

Comment: OK, first of all, that's awesome, thank you.   Second of all, I didn't even know about the #using directive in C++/CLI (shame on me).  Third of all, how the heck did you figure that one out?

Comment: Divine intuition.